# Regex Decimal Range Expression. Negative to Positive value

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to make a regex expression that will validate a field (decimal) that should be in this range **-12.0 to +13.0**.

I was able to do this regex expression `^[-+]?(?:[0-9]|[0-1][0-2](?:[.][0-9])?)$` but it's not enough as this will allow -12.9 to +12.9 values and will not validate things like 0 or 0.0.

I know that this is not the best solution and a better approach will be to use the model and add the regex validation using Data Annotation.

Main problem here is that the Model.Value is a string. But I need to validate in many different ways that string before updating the database value. The way I validate that string is by using a foreign key that will tell me the regex expression to use.

Imagine this model.

**ModelA**

```
public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
public virtual IList<ModelB> ModelB{ get; set; }
```

**Model B**

```
public virtual string Value { get; set; }
public virtual DataType DataType{ get; set; }
```

And in the DataType I have the regex validation for that specific value

That is why I am using this approach...

Can someone help me accomplish this?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to use regex for validation? from your tags it looks like you're using c#.  Why not parse the string to float and validate it?

Comment: Hello Sai Puli. 
Because I do want to do client validation. Its absolutly necessary for me to use Regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "will not validate things like 0 or 0.0."?

Comment: @PaoloGo it means that I do want 0 and 0.0 to be considered valid values.
Thanks

Comment: Doing this with a regular expression that captures all possible cases will lead to something very, very ugly. You should seriously consider to find another way which involves parsing the numbers with `double.Parse()`. Imagine what happens if the range has to be changed to `-13.0 to +14.0` or, even worse, to `-12.5 to +13.5`. Adjusting this incredibly complex regeular expression will be a massive pain in the *** for the next developers or even to you when a month has passed. And that's a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're doing web client side validation you can't use `Decimal.Parse()` (or better `Decimal.TryParse()`) however Data Annotations already have what you need. Assuming you have this property in your ViewModel:

```
public class MyModel {
    [RegularExpression("^[-+]?(?:[0-9]|[0-1][0-2](?:[.][0-9])?)$")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Yes, you **may** fix this regex however they're not the best tool to deal with numerical range validation, expression will quickly become **terribly complex** and - in general - it's **not easy to evolve** to changing requirements (what if you need to validate `(-100..+1000.3]`?) If regex is what you truly need (not just what you thought to use) then go with [AdrianHHH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157220/1207195) (and don't forget to include user's locale handling for decimal separator), if not (and assumption about your environment is valid) then use this:

```
public class MyModel {
    [Range(typeof(decimal), "-12", "13")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

That's all. Please note that if you had `double` instead of `decimal` then it may be further simplified to `[Range(-12.0, 13.0)]`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

---

**EDIT**: according to your edit your scenario is little bit more convoluted however I'd still suggest to do not misuse regex because of this, the *proper* approach (Data Annotations) is still a viable solution. First of all let's create a custom validation class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ComplexLogicAttribute: ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = (MyModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if (IsValueValidForGivenObject(model, Convert.ToString(value)))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        // Or your own error message...
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(null));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "complexlogic",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
        };

        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule> { modelClientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

Where `IsValueValidForGivenObject()` skeleton is:

```
private bool IsValueValidForGivenObject(MyModel model, string value)
{
    decimal minimum = CalculateMinimumAccordingToVeryComplexLogic(model);
    decimal maximum = CalculateMaximumAccordingToMagic(model);

    decimal number;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
        return false;

    if (number < minimum || number > maximum)
        return false;

    return PerformEvenMoreComplexEsotericValidation(model, number);
}
```

Now you have to provide client side validation (let's say in `ComplexLogic.js`, don't forget to include it):

```
$.validator.addMethod("complexlogic", function (value, element, params) {
    // Repeat your validation logic here!
    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("complexlogic", function (options) {
    options.messages["complexlogic"] = options.message;
});
```

Take a look to [this simple tutorial](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/) for a better explanation. That's all, you're validating numbers as numbers and your code is flexible enough...

Comment: Hello @Adriano Repetti 

I am using .net MVC sorry not to mention that.

I cannot use this solution as the Value is a string in My model and the validation for that string will be different depending on a foreign key of that same model. 

Please see my last comment on the page to understand my pain :)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @legollas007 it doesn't matter how much complex your logic is, Data Annotations are flexible enough, no need to _go crazy_ with complex regex (see updated example).

Answer (score 2):

With a target like this I would break the problem in several smaller problems and then consider merging them to make a simpler regular expression.

First negative numbers: `(-(12(\.0*)?|(1[01]|\d)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

```
-(                      # Always have a minus sign, then three alternatives.
     12(\.0*)?          # It can be `12` or `-12.` or `-12.000000`.
  |  (1[01]|\d)         # It can be a `10` or a `11` or any single digit,
             (\.\d*)?   #     optionally followed by a fractional part.
  |  \.\d+              # It can be just a fractional part.
 )
```

Zeroes and positive numbers are almost identical. The `+` is optional, the `13` is the special case and the two-digit set now includes `12` hence: `\+?(13(\.0*)?|(1[012]|\d)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

We can then combine the two expressions as alternatives, giving:

```
((-(12(\.0*)?|(1[01]|\d)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+))|(\+?(13(\.0*)?|(1[012]|\d)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)))
```

This has lots of captures that are not interesting. They could all be non-capturing but the expression is simpler without the extra `?:` characters. But it is good to add them in at this stage. Leading to:

```
^((?:-(?:12(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[01]|\d)(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))|(?:\+?(?:13(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[012]|\d)(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)))$
```

The question is not clear on the treatment of leading zeros, i.e. whether values such as `-00011.9` and `000.0001` and `+012.3` are included or excluded. If leading zeroes are allowed then add a `0*` after the `-` or `+`. Have also changed the `\d` for matching a single digit to `[1-9]` to avoid the ambiguity about where a single leading zero in e.g. `0.123` should be matched. The final expression is:

```
((?:-0*(?:12(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[01]|[1-9])(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))|(?:\+?0*(?:13(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[012]|[1-9])(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)))
```

---

Tested in C# with a selection of numbers, one per line, by using the regular expression

```
@"^((?:-0*(?:12(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[01]|[1-9])(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))|(?:\+?0*(?:13(?:\.0*)?|(?:1[012]|[1-9])(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)))$"
```

---

Responding to comments it seems that the requirement is a number that matches the regular expression `[-+]\d\d?\.\d` and that is in the range `-12.0 <= number <= +13.0`.

Reworking the last regular expression above to meet these needs gives the following. If a leading `+` is not allowed then omit the `\+?` from the expression.

```
((?:-(?:12\.0|(?:1[01]|\d)\.\d))|(?:\+?(?:13\.0|(?:1[012]|\d)\.\d)))
```

(Removed the leading zeroes; changed multiple fractional digits to be a single digit; removed the `.\d` option.)

Comment: @llegollas007 - Adriano and others are correct, regular expressions are probably the wrong method. The regular expression in my answer is horrible. If at all possible, please do not use a regular expression for your task. However you asked for a regular expression and I wanted to show how one might be created for your task.

Comment: @legollas007 If your last comment refers to wanting 0 and 0.0 to be valid then my answer is OK, otherwise not sure what you mean by *"please read my last comment on the page "*. The expression in my answer here passes `-12.0` and `+13.0` but rejects `-12.0000001` and `13.0000001`.

Comment: Hello again @AdrianHHH

Thanks a lot for your help. I know that my approach is not the best but please read my last comment on the page to understand the reason I am doing this.

Maybe I have not explained correctly but the range of values that I want to be valid are:

-12.0 to +13.0

So some examples are:

-12.0
...
-11.5
...
-0.5
...
0.0 or 0
...
+0.9
...
+1.0
...
+5.5
...
+13.0

I would prefer not to use leading zeros and only 1 decimal place.

Many thanks for your help and explanation. I really appreciate and will try to help other in same way.